# Control node-webkit App with AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript, chromium, node-webkit

I'd like to execute JavaScript code in my node-webkit application from an AppleScript. Don't know if this is reasonable or possible, though.

This works without problems of course:

```
tell application "appname" to activate
```

But if I would like to execute JavaScript in my app, it fails ('Expected end of line but found number.' in line 2 - [code from Chromium examples](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/applescript/examples/execute_javascript.applescript)):

```
tell application "appname"
    tell tab 1 of window 1
        execute javascript "alert('Hello World')"
    end tell
end tell
```

Exchange "appname" for "Chrome" and there it works fine and the alert is displayed. Guess it is because my nw app has no tabs?

Might you be able to give me a hint? Probably [this resource](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/applescript) might help, as node-webkit is based on Chromium?